# How to convert the result of DataFrame groupby().agg() to a new Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Sounds basic, but...
I have a dataframe df with (yy, mm, dd, value1, value2,...)

```
df1 = df.groupby(['yy','dd'], as_index = False).agg({'value1':['count'],'value2':['sum']})
```

working ok, returning a df1 multi index object, that I can 'visualize' e.g. `df1.info()`

Q: how to convert this df1 into a 'basic' 2D DataFrame.

Comment: What do you mean by basic 2D DataFrame? Do you mean without the multi index?

Comment: Indeed without the multi index, a sort the 'final' result of this groupby().agg() operation. Thks

Comment: Ok, can you please share a sample of your data?

Comment: `df1.reset_index()` is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the multilevel from the pandas column, and then reset index. You can try this:-

```
df.groupby(['yy','dd'], as_index = True).agg({'value1':['count'],'value2':['sum']})
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Good advice. I just had to define the level df1.columns.droplevel(1) to keep the columns 'names'. Thanks a lot. Stay SAFE .

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer if it solved your query.